# Wordpress redirects URL though it shouldn't

Tags: wordpress

Everything works just fine in my WordPress installation when I am using standard installation but when I try to enable multisite, then URL is redirected.

I insert into browser : `localhost/wordpress/wp-admin`, but it tries to go to `localhost/wordpress1/wp-admin`

Thats the exact address it goes: `http://localhost/wordpress1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

And all i get is 404 error.

Some time ago i changed my wp-config.php file. And then i changed those rows:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/wordpress' ); 
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/wordpress' );
```

to

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/wordpress1' ); 
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/wordpress1' );
```

but i changed them back to default, so why my browser still redirects me to wordpress1 instead of wordpress when i try to enable multisite?

The funny thing is, when i change my wordpress folder in htdocs to wordpress1, then my browser wont redirect me, but tries to go to localhost/wordpress and tells it doesnt find that. It's very odd.

I am pretty sure that I have done everything right in enabling multisite, so I wont post changes I made in wp-config.php and .htacces files.

I really want to know what causes this problem not just reinstall wordpress to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen on other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it happens on explorer and on mozilla too. In addition to chrome.